# Html Extension methods are not accessible in MVC Partial Pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Hi I'm trying to create a declarative Html helper method inside MVC partial page, everything works fine. But when I want to use built-in Html extension methods, I see there are no extension methods. Also I checked my view's webconfig file to add `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace. everything is OK, but I don't know why it's not working.

Any advice will be helpful.

**Edit** : Here is my code :

```
@using WebVoter.ViewModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper GetVoteList(IList<VoteQuestionViewModel> voteQuestionList)
{

    <div class="head-panel">
        @*For example ActionLink is not accessible here*@
        @Html.ActionLink(....);

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Have you added the using statement?  Similar to a partial class, this needs to be in your partial view.

Comment: do you try explicit using in the view ?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : I updated my post. take a look

Comment: @BlueChippy : yes chippy. take a look for update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Razor helpers you do not have reference to `HtmlHelper`. You need to pass it as parameter from the calling code:

```
@helper GetVoteList(HtmlHelper html, IList<VoteQuestionViewModel> voteQuestionList)
{
    <div class="head-panel">
        @html.ActionLink(....)
    </div>
}
```

and when you want to call this helper from some view you need to pass the reference:

```
@GetVoteList(Html, ...)
```

Personally I've always preferred writing extension methods to the HtmlHelper class instead of using those inline Razor helpers. They would then be used as standard helpers:

```
@Html.GetVoteList(...)
```

The advantage is that you are no longer tied to Razor. Extension methods are view engine agnostic and make transition to other view engines less painful because they are C# code. Another benefit is that they can be unit tested.

Comment: +1 : thank you Darin it worked, but could you explain why partial doesn't have any reference to HtmlHelper?

Comment: I never said that partials don't have reference to HtmlHelper. Partials and views do have reference to HtmlHelper. What I said is that Razor inline helpers do not have reference to HtmlHelper. The reason for this is unknown to me, you will have to ask the designers of the MVC framework. I guess it's because as you know, `Html` is a property of the ViewPage, but Razor inline helpers are compiled as some static functions or whatever and no longer have any reference to the containing page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a web.config under Views folder. Can you modify this config too?